# How to get SSIS 2012 to skip the last 28 rows when I use flat flie connector

Tags: ssis-2012

Hi I've created a data flow task that uses a flat file to import a csv file. But I want the last 28 rows to be skipped. So After the flat file connector I am saving the row count to a variable. How do I get the data flow to take the row count and subtract 28. So out of 100 rows that are brought in only import 72 rows.

thanks

Comment: I researched this and couldn't find a quick answer - Do the last 28 rows have 'bad' data or some other anomaly? Could you load it with a rownumber attached and then drop the last rows? Just throwing it out there as an idea since I don't have an answer.  If the last rows have a unique or defining characteristic, you could filter based on that value(s) instead of the row number, if that makes sense.

Comment: @Aron When I do a csv pull the last 28 rows have info from when the report is created. Like who created the report, report date, and different filters used.

Comment: Take a look at this post http://www.techbrothersit.com/2014/09/ssis-how-to-delete-bottom-n-rows-from.html -- they use a C# script to trim the file, and then you can ingest it like you normally would. Otherwise, you may be able to use a conditional split to identify rows that you don't want to import. http://geekswithblogs.net/Compudicted/archive/2011/02/15/ssis-technique-to-removeskip-trailer-andor-bad-data-row-in.aspx